# Proof that $a_n \leq b_n$ implies that $\limsup a_n \leq \limsup b_n$.

Tags: proof-explanation, limsup-and-liminf

I am trying to prove that for sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$, that if $a_n \leq b_n$ for all $n \geq m$, then $\limsup\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n \leq \limsup\limits_{n \to \infty} b_n$. This is part three of Lemma 6.4.13. in Tao's analysis textboo, so I am a bit limited in terms of what I am allowed to  use. Here is what I have so far.

By definition, we have 
\begin{align*}
\limsup\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = \inf(a_N^+)_{N=m}^{\infty}
\limsup\limits_{n \to \infty} b_n = \inf(b_N^+)_{N=m}^{\infty}.
\end{align*}
But $\limsup\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = \inf(a_N^+)_{N=m}^{\infty}$ and $\limsup\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = \inf(a_N^+)_{N=m}^{\infty}$ are non-increasing sequences, so:
\begin{align*}
a_1^+ \geq a_m^+ \; \forall m > 1 \\
b_1^+ \geq b_m^+ \; \forall m > 1 
\end{align*}
We therefore have:
\begin{align*}
a_1^+ \geq \sup(a_N^+)_{N=1}^{\infty} \\
b_1^+ \geq \sup(b_N^+)_{N=1}^{\infty}
\end{align*}
This is the step that I am most unsure about, though I know there must be some way to tie together the two series, from which the result should follow directly.

Any helpful comments would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There is no loss of generality taking $m=1$.

The sequences $a_N^+$ and $b_N^+$ are nonincreasing hence both convergent (possibly to $\pm \infty$).

Fix an index $N$.  If $n \ge N$ then
$$a_n \le b_n \le b_N^+$$
so that $b_N^+$ is an upper bound of the set $\{a_n\}_{n \ge N}$. That is, $a_N^+ \le b_N^+$. Now take the limit as $N \to \infty$ and apply the fact that limits preserve inequality.